# how to get top 5 food in this sql query

Tags: php, mysql

cannot get top 5 food for this query. count top 5 food in that restaurant.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require('config.php');

$sqlQuery = "SELECT top 5 fd.name as res_name,(SELECT  count(*) from review re where re.favorite_food=fd.id and re.res_id='1' ) AS count FROM  food fd ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sqlQuery);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($connection);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

occurs error

Comment: i mean count the top 5  (mysql)

Comment: What do you mean by error? Please describe precisely the desired behavior and the current output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT fd.name as res_name, count(*)
FROM food fd
JOIN review re ON re.favorite_food = fd.id
WHERE re.res_id = 1
GROUP BY fd.name
ORDER BY count(*) desc
LIMIT 5
```